# How to use the public struct of an object in a class

Tags: c#, oop, class, struct

So, I have this class and struct:

```
class CarCollection
{
    //struct contenant les informations pour décrire une voiture de la collection
    public struct voiture
    {
        public string marque, couleur, condition;
        public int annee;
        public DateTime dateAcquisition, dateVente;
        public double prix;
    }
    ...
```

What I want is to be able to create a variable of the type of this struct in the class where I have the object containing this struct :

```
class Program
{
    static CarCollection collection;
    ...
    voiture temp = new voiture();
    //or
    collection.voiture temp = new collection.voiture();
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try `new CarCollection.voiture()`.

Comment: Note: Your stucture doesn't represent a single entity, it's larger than 16 bytes, and it's not mutable. Consider using a class instead.

Comment: It's clearly stated in the assignement so I don't have the choice...

Comment: @Guffa: Did you mean and it *is* mutable?

Comment: @Mostaguen: If you're being forced to abuse structs like this, you should *at least* complain. There's no reason for it to be nested, or a struct, or to have public fields. Please protest, for the sake of future students if no-one else.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, sort of. I meant to write *it's not immutable*, but obviously lost the line of though in the middle... :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to initialize a `voiture` you have to access it via the outer class, since the full-name is `CarCollection.voiture`:

```
 CarCollection.voiture v = new CarCollection.voiture();
```

You're using an instance of the outer class to reference the struct.

[Nested Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx)